# Proper nested loop, back to basic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails 3.2. I want to understand how to write proper recursive loop. Here's the association and controller:

```
# country.rb
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
end

# state.rb
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :zones
  has_many :cities, :through => :zones
end

# zone.rb
class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :city
end

# city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :photos, :as => :attachable
end

# photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
  has_attached_file :data, :options
end

# countries_controller.rb
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @country = Country.find(params[:id], :includes => [:states => [:cities => :photos]])
    @photos = @country.country_photos
  end
end
```

I am gonna write a stupid recursive loop below to explain what I am trying to achieve: get photos from the cities:

```
# countries/show.html.erb
<%= @country.country_photos.inspect # just to test %>

# country.rb
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  def country_photos
    all_photos = []
    self.states.each do |state|
      state.cities.each do |city|
        city.photos.each do |photo|
          all_photos << photo
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
# Expected output: [photo_object_1, photo_object_2]
```

I have tried using `map` in the `country_photos`:

```
if (photos = state.map(&:cities).flatten.map(&:photos).flatten)
  photos
end
```

But it has performance issue: 400ms to execute.

What is the proper way to write a recursive loop? Appreciate if step-by-step explanation is given. Thanks.

Comment: That's a *nested* loop, [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) is something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use has_many :through, you have already used it.

```
# country.rb
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :states
  has_many :cities, :through => :states
  has_many :photos, :through => :cities
end

# state.rb
class State < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :zones
  has_many :cities, :through => :zones
end

# zone.rb
class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :city
end

# city.rb
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :photos, :as => :attachable
end

# photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true
  has_attached_file :data, :options
end

# countries_controller.rb
class CountriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @country = Country.find(params[:id])
    @photos = @country.photos
  end
end
```

Comment: What to change in `country_photos`?

Comment: You don't need country_photos anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the performance but you may try to setting benchmark:

```
def country_photos
    Photo.where("city_id IN (select id from cities where cities.state_id IN (select states.id from states where country_id = ?))", self.id)
end
```

if you cities table contains country_id then it could be written as:

```
def country_photos
   Photo.where("city_id IN (select id from cities where cities.country_id = ?)", self.id)
end
```